# I need config Collapsed Topics of course in moodle mobile app

Tags: moodle, moodle-mobile

I clone the moodle mobile app from git and config my local. already I have a server and it includes moodle web and config it properly on the server. also i config site URL in my mobile app and log in to in. then I go to the dashboard then select course. it appears as below.

[Course inside categories appear as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0kZV.jpg)

but I want to config it as Collapsed Topics of course categories. any one can help me plz?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.